# Different views on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I'm using SharePoint Online (Office 365).
When upgrading our old site from 2010 version to 2013 version (current version of SPO), there are some list view displays in modern style like this:

[image: Modern New item]

but some list still displays in old 2010 style like this:

[image: Classic style Add new item]

Why are they different? I tried create new view of them but nothing changes. All view settings are the same.
Is there any setting that decides the view style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a script file that makes all SharePoint views in the lists look modern:

> /_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js

You can add a link to this file in the list's web part:
[image: Add the script file manually]

If you don't include this link it will look like so:

[image]

Also, you might not need it, but if you are updating Visual Studio sandbox solutions for Office 365 from SP2010 to SP2013 you need in all schema.xml files that contain list definitions include a JSLink property:

[image: JSLink property]

Comment: Perfect answer!